# Copying render target texture loses all depth

Tags: xna, depth-buffer, rendertargets

I have a render target `RenderTargetScene` that holds my scene texture with the scene's depth buffer

```
            rtScene = new RenderTarget2D(
            graphicsDevice,
            graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
            false,
            SurfaceFormat.Rgba64,
            DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8, // Requires a depth format for objects
              // to be drawn correctly (e.g. wireframe model surrounding model)
            0,
            RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents
            );
```

If I attempt to copy the render target contents to another render target using the following code

```
        game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTargets(sceneCopy);

        game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.Transparent, 0f, 0);
        //game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        game.SpriteBatch.Begin(
            SpriteSortMode.Immediate,
            BlendState.Opaque,
            SamplerState.PointClamp,
            DepthStencilState.Default,
            RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise
            );

        game.SpriteBatch.Draw(game.RenderTargetScene,
             new Rectangle(0, 0, sceneCopy.Width, sceneCopy.Height), Color.White);

        game.SpriteBatch.End();
```

Then the texture is copied across but the depth buffer appears to be lost.

This is apparent when using `DepthStencilState.DepthRead` as there is no depth for the objects drawn with that render state to read.

How can I make sure the depth buffer is copied across too?

EDIT:

I have a depth texture created via my deferred rendering system so I thought I would use that.

I'm now drawing a full screen quadrangle using a depth writing shader

```
    public void RestoreDepthBuffer(Texture2D depthTexture)
    {
        // Set the render states
        game.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        game.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        game.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
        game.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;

        Effect effect = restoreDepthBuffer;

        effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Default"];

        effect.Parameters["DepthTexture"].SetValue(depthTexture);

        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

        game.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(
            PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip,
            NearPlaneVerticesVPT,
            0,
            4,
            Indices,
            0,
            2
            );
    }
```

The important parts of the shader look like

```
struct PixelShaderOutput
{
   float4 Colour                        : COLOR0;
   float Depth                          : DEPTH;
};

PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PixelShaderOutput output;

    output.Colour = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    output.Depth = 1.0f - tex2D(DepthSampler, input.TextureCoordinates).r;

    return output;
}
```

This is still not working though.

EDIT2:  I've got it to work but I have to set the depth and draw all the objects when the RenderTarget is first set and not unset it again.

Should I post an answer based on my working method?

Comment: I have found this [link](http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/12-months-12-samples-2008/restoring-the-depth-buffer/). I'll try that when I return from work.

Comment: This doesn't do what I want unfortunately without redrawing the entire scene.  There must be a better way.

Comment: So, to summarize, you want to copy the content of one `RenderTarget2D` to another `RenderTarget2D`, without losing the associated Z-Buffer? Is that it?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.  My current method is to use a depth texture.